# How to show YouTube dislike counts without using any extension?

Tags: html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, show

Like what I mentioned in the title, how can I always show YouTube dislike counts without using any extension? There are so many helpful tutorial on YouTube, but there are many fake or unhelpful videos as well, just to earn free view counts. I am tired of wasting my time on those fake vids and I don't want to install a bunch of extensions...

If you know how, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Not sure that you can. At least not easily. For what it's worth, I have the Return Youtube dislike extension installed and it works great.

Comment: why don't you want to use an extension? "_I don't want to install a bunch of extensions_" - what makes you think you have to install multiple to get what you want?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the *returnyoutubedislike API*. **NOTE: The only way to make dislikes display in youtube is by extension. This way just shows how to get them.** According to the [documentation](https://www.returnyoutubedislike.com/docs), all you need to do is paste `https://returnyoutubedislikeapi.com/votes?videoId={VideoID}` into your browser, changing `{VideoID}` to the ID of the video (the string following `youtube.com/watch?v=` in youtube URL). You will then get JSON with the data. For more information see [documentation](https://www.returnyoutubedislike.com/docs). However, I personally recommend installing this extension.